# How to create a clear line plot that shows the course of values x against y

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have a pandas DataFrame of 8664 rows. Shown here:
[frame_3_LW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ILwo.png).

frame_3_LW contains the following columns of importance to me: EASTVEL , NORTHVEL, Z_NAP, DATE+TIME. Definitions of the columns are:

- EASTVEL = Flow of current where min(-) values are west and plus(+) values are east.
- NORTHVEL = Flow of current where min(-) values are south and plus(+) values are north.
- Z_NAP = Depth of water
- DATE+TIME = Date + time in this format: 2021-11-17 10:00:00

**Now the problem that I encouter is the following:** I want to generate a plot with EASTVEL on the x-axis and Z_NAP on the y-axis.

I used a simple:

```
df.plot(x = 'EASTVEL', y = 'Z_NAP')
```

[image: plot output]

However because I have so many values I get an unclear plot with a lot of lines. However I would like just one line describing the course of EASTVEL (x axis) against Z_NAP (y axis). Can anybody help me with that? It would be such a big help!

Comment: What do you mean? You already have one line...

Comment: These are seperate lines for all the measurement instances. Which makes it really hard to read. I want to see just one line that shows the course of x against y axis and goes through all instances instead of plotting a new line for every instance.

Comment: I think you should provide a sample of your dataframe `frame_3_LW` to have a chance to get help.  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have added frame_3_lw to the beginning of the text. If possible please provide me with an answer.

Comment: as for me all problem is that you have some mess data in DataFrame. You can't get nice plot if you have mess in data. Normally for `x`  we use increasing values like `0,1,2,3,...` but your `EASTVEL` has very random values. Maybe you should use `index` or `unnamed: 0` as `x` instead of `EASTVEL`. OR you should plot two lines: `EASTVEL` as `y`) with `index` as `x`, and `Z_NAP` as another `y` also with `index` as `x`